# Determine base image version installed in docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dependencies, artifactory, docker-image

I have an old image on artifactory. The Dockerfile had installed the latest versions of the base image and the latest versions don't work anymore. I wanted to rebuild the docker image I have, but since it was using "latest", I don't actually know what base image version was used when the image was built. Is there any way to determine the base image version?

Comment: can you provide snippet of your Dockerfile to help with debugging

Comment: Also, can you provide output of 'docker history image', here image is the one you downloaded from artifactory and not the one built on your system from Dockerfile